# I only can check the first column of an 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wrote that memory puzzle with sprites an I have some bugs:
1.- When I move the mouse over the boxes only the first column displays the highlight effect.
2.- Again, only the first column displays the effect of covered boxes

[the complete program in github](https://github.com/Adri-md-1208/Memory-puzzle/blob/master/main.py)

I think that the problem is that functions:

```py
def cartesianToPositional(x, y):
    '''
    That function is used to check if the mouse is over a box. In that case, the function return the position of the 
    box on which is over in the 2D list positional order
    '''
    for boxx in range(COLUMNS):
        for boxy in range(ROWS):
            left, top = positionalToCartesian(boxx, boxy)
            boxRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE)
            if boxRect.collidepoint(x, y): # That method is used to check if the x, y position is colliding with the boxRect
                return (boxx, boxy)
        return (None, None)
```

```
def drawHighlightBox(boxx, boxy):
    '''
    This function draw a perimether around the box passed with the highlightcolor
    '''
    left, top = positionalToCartesian(boxx, boxy)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, HIGHLIGHTCOLOR, (left - 5, top - 5, BOXSIZE + 10, BOXSIZE + 10), 4) # 4 is for the width of the line

def drawBoxCovers(board, boxes, cover):
    '''
    This function cover the icons if is needed
    '''
    for box in boxes:
        left, top = positionalToCartesian(box[0], box[1])
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, BGCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
        ball = getBall(board, box[0], box[1])
        drawIcon(ball, box[0], box[1])
        if cover > 0: 
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) issue. In `cartesianToPositional`, the return statement ( `return (None, None)`) has to be at the end of the function, rather than in the outer loop:

```py
def cartesianToPositional(x, y):

    for boxx in range(COLUMNS):
        for boxy in range(ROWS):
            left, top = positionalToCartesian(boxx, boxy)
            boxRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE)
            if boxRect.collidepoint(x, y): 
                return (boxx, boxy)

    # <--
    return (None, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your source code you have an early return in one of your functions.

```
def cartesianToPositional(x, y):
    '''
    That function is used to check if the mouse is over a box. In that case, the function return the position of the 
    box on which is over in the 2D list positional order
    '''
    for boxx in range(COLUMNS):
        for boxy in range(ROWS):
            left, top = positionalToCartesian(boxx, boxy)
            boxRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE)
            if boxRect.collidepoint(x, y): # That method is used to check if the x, y position is colliding with the boxRect
                return (boxx, boxy)
        # This prevents your outer for loop from completing
        return (None, None)
```

Remove one level of indentation on `return (none, None)` and it should work fine.